# Moving table row to another table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code below that prints the value of `random fruits` table whenever i click the cell value. The problem is i'm trying to create a function that allows me to move the value of `random fruits` table into the red fruits table by clicking on for example `kiwi` and it will move into the red fruits table and also i want to be able to move back that value i moved into `red fruits` table back to the `random fruits` table. I tried to do it using the array push method but it only copies the value into the other table and not completely move it. Is there any easy way to do this any suggestion would be greatly appreciated thanks!

```js
var obj = {};
var obj2 = {};

var key = "Red Fruits";
obj[key] = ['Apple', 'Cherry', 'Strawberry'];
var myArray = [];
myArray.push(obj);

var key2 = "Green Fruits";
obj[key2] = ['Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado'];
var myArray2 = [];
myArray2.push(obj);

var key3 = "Random Fruits";
obj2[key3] = ['Kiwi', 'Pomegranate', 'Honeydew', 'Plum'];
var myArray3 = [];
myArray3.push(obj2);

var $header = $("<tr>"),
  cols = 0,
  bodyString = "";

$.each(obj, function(key, values) {
  cols = Math.max(cols, values.length);
  $header.append($('<th/>').text(key + ": " + values.length));
});
for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
  bodyString += '<tr>';
  $.each(obj, function(key, values) {
    bodyString += '<td>' +
      (values[i] ? values[i] : "") +
      '</td>';
  });
  bodyString += '</tr>';
}
$('.fruitsclass thead').html($header);
$('.fruitsclass tbody').html(bodyString);

var bodyString = '';
var headString = '';
$.each(obj2[key3], function(index) {
  bodyString += ('<tr><td>' + obj2[key3][index] + '</td></tr>');
});
headString += ('<tr><th>' + 'Random Fruits' + '</th></tr>');
$('.fruityclass tbody').html(bodyString);
$('.fruityclass thead').html(headString);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#fruityid td").click(function() {
    getval(this);
  });
});

function getval(cel) {
  alert(cel.innerHTML);
}
```

```css
.class {
  font-family: Open Sans;
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center
}

.skillsTable th {
  border-left: 1px solid #AAA5A4;
  border-right: 1px solid #AAA5A4;
}

table {
  float: left;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 70%
}

td {
  border-left: 1px solid #AAA5A4;
  border-right: 1px solid #AAA5A4;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-left: 11px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

th {
  color: #0080ff;
  font-weight: normal;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #AAA5A4;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

div {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="//#" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="result"> </div>
  <div class="center">
    <table id="fruitsid" class="fruitsclass skillsTable class">
      <thead></thead>
      <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <table id="fruityid" class="fruityclass skillsTable class">
      <thead></thead>
      <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `I tried to do it using the array push method but it only copies the value into the other table and not completely move it.` I didnt get the same result from the DEMO

Comment: @guradio this is the other version  jsfiddle.net/gnm8wv5f

Comment: Isn't it same as what you asked yesterday? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50792668/append-table-array-value-to-another-array ? I commented with https://jsfiddle.net/gnm8wv5f/

Comment: You'll want to use the jQuery [`.remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) function to remove whatever fruit was clicked on ( `$(this).remove()` ) and then simply add it back into the red fruit table, so something like `$('#fruitsid > tbody:last-child').append($(this).remove())`.  You probably want to use unique `id`s though.  There's a bunch of questions that explain how to use `.append()` (and it's relatives)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working on top of your code, changed `listener` function to remove the node:

```
function listener(obj) {
    tbl = document.getElementById("fruitsTable");
        if (tbl != null) {
            for (var i = 0; i < tbl.rows.length; i++) {
              for (var j = 0; j < tbl.rows[i].cells.length; j++)
                     tbl.rows[i].cells[j].onclick = function () { 
                    getval(this);
                    data = this.innerHTML;
                    k1 = Object.keys(obj).find(k => obj[k].indexOf(data) >= 0 )
                    if (k1 != 'Random Fruits') {
                      key = 'Random Fruits'
                    } else { 
                      key = 'Red Fruits';
                    }
                    index = obj[k1].indexOf(data);
                    obj[k1].splice(index, 1);
                    obj[key].push(data);                    
                    redraw(obj);
                    listener(obj);
               };
            }
        }
 }
```

It finds the relevant *key* and removes the element from that array, and pushes that into `k2`. Once done, it redraws the UI.

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/wqzsn7ou/

Comment: Thanks man you saved me but may i ask you a question im currently trying to implement your code into my newer version of the table. Having some problems in implementing it do you mind helping me see if im impletmenting it wrong or something?  http://jsfiddle.net/hg1cLqyk/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/prq7gcuy/. Also, you only added listener on fruityid, i assume it's intended.