# Removing elements from table and adding them to other table

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I made this simple webpage that adds elements to table. On every element there is a post and remove button. Ignore post button because that is functioning. How can I make whenever I click on remove button for that specific row to be moved to other table named `removed elements` and removing them from the main table?

```js
var title = document.getElementById("title");
var author = document.getElementById("author");
var output = document.getElementById("output");

function addToTable() {
  output.innerHTML += "<tr>" + "<td>" + title.value + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + author.value + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + "<input type='button' onclick='post(this);' id='post' value ='Post'>" +
    "<input type='button' onclick='remove(this);' id='remove'value ='Remove'>" + "</td>" + "</tr>"
}

function remove(btn) {
  var row = btn.parentNode.parentNode;
  var removed = document.getElementById("removed");
  removed.innerHTML += "<div>" + row.parentNode.value + "</div>";
  row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
}

function post(btn) {
  var row = btn.parentNode;
  row.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "Green";
  btn.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
  btn.parentNode.lastElementChild.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
}
```

```css
label {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

table,
th,
td,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <div>
      <label for="Title">Title</label>
      <input type="text" id="title">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="Author">Author</label>
      <input type="text" id="author">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addToTable();">
  </div>
  <div>
    <table id="output">
      <th style="width:45%;">Title</th>
      <th style="width:45%;">Author</th>
      <th style="width:10%;">Button</th>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>Removed elements</h1>
    <table id="removed">

    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Related: [Moving table row to another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50810566/moving-table-row-to-another-table)

Comment: Just `.append()` them on the target table (as child of the `<tbody>`)

Comment: Do not use `removeChild` for that, just use `appendChild` to append the element where you want it to go. Appending / inserting a node that is already in the document, will automatically remove it from its current location.

Comment: @CBroe yes but i want them to be removed from the main table after i move them to my removed table.. btw how can i get the row from the main table ?

Comment: Instead of adding a new line up to the removed data table, why don't you try to make the table on the other side refreshed every time the element gets removed?

Comment: _"yes but i want them to be removed from the main table after i move them to my removed table"_ - no "yes but." As I just told you, you _only_ need to append the element in the new target location. It will _automatically_ be removed from its current location, when you do that.

Comment: @CBroe :OO it works let me put the answer and can you explain it to me how it works ?

Comment: Explain how what works, why the element gets removed from its current position, when you append it somewhere else? That simply _is_ how it works ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild: _"If the given child is a reference to an existing node in the document, appendChild() moves it from its current position to the new position (there is no requirement to remove the node from its parent node before appending it to some other node)."_

Comment: Yes but what does `removed.append(row)` do in this case like without it it doesn't work. I tried it using appendChild on the place where it was removeChild and i wasn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will do that this way...

```js
const
  title     = document.getElementById('title')
, author    = document.getElementById('author')
, btAdd     = document.getElementById('bt-Add')
, T_output     = document.querySelector('#t-output')
, T_output_tb  = document.querySelector('#t-output tbody')
, T_removed    = document.querySelector('#t-removed')
, T_removed_tb = document.querySelector('#t-removed tbody')
  ;
btAdd.onclick = () =>
  {
  let 
    inTittle = title.value.trim()
  , inAuthor = author.value.trim()
    ;
  if ( inTittle !== ''
    && inAuthor !== '' 
    ){
    title.value = ''
    author.value = ''
    title.focus()

    let newRow = T_output_tb.insertRow()
    newRow.insertCell().textContent = inTittle
    newRow.insertCell().textContent = inAuthor
    newRow.insertCell().innerHTML = `<button class="bt-post">Post</button>`
                                  + `<button class="bt-remove">Remove</button>`
    }
  }
T_output_tb.onclick = e =>
  {
  if (!e.target.matches('button.bt-post, button.bt-remove')) return

  let tRow = e.target.closest('tr')

  if (e.target.matches('button.bt-remove'))
    {
    if (!T_removed.tHead)
      {
      let headRow = T_removed.createTHead().insertRow()
      headRow.appendChild( T_output.querySelector('thead th:nth-child(1)').cloneNode(true) )
      headRow.appendChild( T_output.querySelector('thead th:nth-child(2)').cloneNode(true) )
      }

    tRow.deleteCell(2)
    T_removed.appendChild( tRow)
    }
  if (e.target.matches('button.bt-post'))
    {
    tRow.classList.add('green')
    tRow.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(bt=>bt.disabled = true)
    }
  }
```

```css
body {
  font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size   : 16px;
  }
label {
  width   : 3em;
  display : inline-block;
  }
table {
  border-collapse  : separate;
  border-spacing   : 1px;
  background-color : darkblue;
  margin           : 1em; 
  }
th, td {
  border     : none;
  background : whitesmoke;
  padding    : .3em .6em;
  }
th {
  min-width : 10em;
  }
th:nth-child(3) {
  min-width : 5em;
  }
td button:first-of-type {
  margin-right: .2em;
  }
tr.green td {
  background: lightgreen;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <label for="Title">Title</label>
    <input type="text" id="title">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="Author">Author</label>
    <input type="text" id="author">
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <button id="bt-Add">Add</button>
</div>
<div>
  <table id="t-output">
    <thead>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Author</th>
      <th>Button</th>        
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>Removed elements</h1>
  <table id="t-removed">
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer i just changed the remove function.

```js
var title = document.getElementById("title");
var author = document.getElementById("author");
var output = document.getElementById("output");

function addToTable() {
  output.innerHTML += "<tr>" + "<td>" + title.value + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + author.value + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + "<input type='button' onclick='post(this);' id='post' value ='Post'>" +
    "<input type='button' onclick='remove(this);' id='remove'value ='Remove'>" + "</td>" + "</tr>"
}

   

function remove(btn){
            var row = btn.parentNode.parentNode;
            var removed = document.getElementById("removed");
            removed.append(row);
            row.parentNode.appendChild(row);
    }

function post(btn) {
  var row = btn.parentNode;
  row.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "Green";
  btn.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
  btn.parentNode.lastElementChild.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
}
```

```css
label {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

table,
th,
td,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <div>
      <label for="Title">Title</label>
      <input type="text" id="title">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="Author">Author</label>
      <input type="text" id="author">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addToTable();">
  </div>
  <div>
    <table id="output">
      <th style="width:45%;">Title</th>
      <th style="width:45%;">Author</th>
      <th style="width:10%;">Button</th>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>Removed elements</h1>
    <table id="removed">

    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: `row.parentNode.appendChild(row);` is completely superfluous. With that, you are only appending the element to the exact same parent it is already in, once more.

Comment: @CBroe yes thanks, one more question i am sorry :D, what if i want when i click remove only the title to be moved to remove table.

Comment: and everything else be removed

Comment: Well then you need to remove the extra cells from that row.

Comment: @CBroe is there a function for that or i need to implement it my self ?